# Scrapy ignore noindex

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I am crawling a large number of URLs and was wondering if it possible to have scrapy not parse pages with 'meta name="robots" content="noindex"'?
Looking at the deny rules listed here http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html it looks like the deny rules only apply to URLs.  Can you have scrapy ignore a xpath?

```
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor

from wallspider.items import Website


class Spider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "browsetest"
    allowed_domains = ["www.mydomain.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.mydomain.com",]

    rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('/browse/')), callback="parse_items", follow= True),
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(),unique=True,deny=('/[1-9]$', '(bti=)[1-9]+(?:\.[1-9]*)?', '(sort_by=)[a-zA-Z]', '(sort_by=)[1-9]+(?:\.[1-9]*)?', '(ic=32_)[1-9]+(?:\.[1-9]*)?', '(ic=60_)[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]*)?', '(search_sort=)[1-9]+(?:\.[1-9]*)?', 'browse-ng.do\?', '/page/', '/ip/', 'out\+value', 'fn=', 'customer_rating', 'special_offers', 'search_sort=&', 'facet=' ))),
    )

    def parse_items(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        sites = hxs.select('//html')
        items = []

        for site in sites:
            item = Website()
            item['url'] = response.url
            item['canonical'] = site.xpath('//head/link[@rel="canonical"]/@href').extract()
            item['robots'] = site.select('//meta[@name="robots"]/@content').extract()
            items.append(item)

        return items
```

Comment: You want to skip retrieving those pages? If so, that wouldn't be possible because in order to lookup for the meta robots you have to retrieve the page.

Comment: Sorry, I've rephrased my question.  Is it possible to have it not parse URLs that contain  'meta name="robots" content="noindex"'?

Comment: Do you want to NOT follow links from a page with noindex? In that case  you can skip the response when the noindex is present. Can you share a simplified version of your spider? Are you using `CrawlSpider` class?

Comment: thanks @Rho For some reason it does not correctly format my 'code'. As a workaround I decided to identify pages with a noindex in them

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `CrawlSpider` does not provide an option for what you want to do. Nevertheless, you can override its methods to achieve that.

Try adding this method to your spider:

```
    def _response_downloaded(self, response):
        # Check whether this page contains the meta noindex in order to skip the processing.
        sel = Selector(response)
        if sel.xpath('//meta[@content="noindex"]'):
            return

        return super(Spider, self)._response_downloaded(response)
```

Whenever the documentation is not enough, you can check the source code to see what you can change and where, just be careful on what version you are using. You can browser the latest source code in github: https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/contrib/spiders/crawl.py#L61

But better to check the source code in your system. If you are using IPython that easily done with the `??` operator.

Comment: Great tip on the source code - I'm new to python and programming and your help has helped me tremendously.

Comment: For another crawler, how would I go about parsing only if the meta content contained noindex? `return super(Spider, self).parse_items(response)`?

Comment: @Murdrae yes, move the `return super(...` inside the if-block.